# HTML - Text (with links) over image

Tags: html

I am attempting to create simple text over image, but I can't work it out.

I have created a <div id="banner> and within this division I have included an image and two paragraph tags for the text. I have also used <A Herf=> to link the text to another HTML .doc

I am also trying to separate the text horizontally across the image with the &nbsp command.

I am currently a Student, not an expert.

here is the Code (HTML only) No CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-/W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN">

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>My Personal Website</TITLE>
<<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\shane\OneDrive\Documents\HTML\Shane_Currie_Resume_HTML\Testing\CSS\testing.css" />
</HEAD>

<BODY>

This is a test page . Currently testing Text over Image

<div id="banner">
  <img src="https://wp-assets.futurism.com/2021/02/nasa-panorama-perseverance-mars-rover-landing-site.jpg">
  <p id="home-text"><font size=6><A HREF="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg">Home</A></font> </p>  
  <p id="about_me-text"><font size=6><A HREF="https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/mars-planet.jpg">About me</A></font></p>  
</div>


</body>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Not just the HTML, but CSS as well.

Comment: I have not done any CSS Code. I only know how to use CSS to change text colours, backgrounds, and floats at this time.  I'm assuming that only HTML is required for layering text over images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you seek?

```css
#banner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
This is a test page . Currently testing Text over Image

<div id="banner">
  <img src="https://wp-assets.futurism.com/2021/02/nasa-panorama-perseverance-mars-rover-landing-site.jpg" width="100%">
  <div id="container">
    <span id="home-text">
    <font size=6>
      <A HREF="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg"> Home </A>
    </font>
  </span> &nbsp;
    <span id="about_me-text">
    <font size=6>
      <A HREF="https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/mars-planet.jpg"> About me </A>
    </font>
  </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, hope this work for you.

//CSS

```
#txtOnImage {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;    
    color: #fff;
}
```

//HTML

```
<div id="banner">
          <img src="https://wp-assets.futurism.com/2021/02/nasa-panorama-perseverance-mars-rover-landing-site.jpg">
          <span id="txtOnImage">This is a test page . Currently testing Text over Image</span>
          <p id="home-text"><font size=6><A HREF="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg">Home</A></font> </p>  
          <p id="about_me-text"><font size=6><A HREF="https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/mars-planet.jpg">About me</A></font></p>  
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.banner .container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img class="banner-img"
    src="https://wp-assets.futurism.com/2021/02/nasa-panorama-perseverance-mars-rover-landing-site.jpg"
    width="100%"
  />
  <div class="container">
    <span class="home-text">
      <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/OSIRIS_Mars_true_color.jpg">
        Home
      </a>
    </span>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="about_me-text">
      <a href="https://www.scienceabc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/mars-planet.jpg">
        About me
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```